# PHP handling duplicate listing to show one at a time?

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing a situation where i have to enable item listing to be duplicate free so far every item has a column named duplicates with this kind of value " 19201935_19210346_19215508_19199482", these are the IDs of other items that are duplicates of the current one, i want to handle this within an array and break the array and re-build the array and then pass it to the actual foreach loop to be displayed on search results.

**for example:**

item ID 19201935 has duplicates that are each 19210346, 19215508 and 19199482.

item ID 19210346 has duplicates that are each 19201935, 19215508 and 19199482.

item ID 19215508 has duplicates that are each 19201935, 19210346 and 19199482.

item ID 19199482 has duplicates that are each 19201935, 19210346 and 19215508.

and its pretty much possible that the next row has something similar with different ids. and they are all passed to the pagination.

I need to filter the array to include only one of each duplicates randomly so on each page refresh a different Item from duplicates be displayed?

I can not change the pre-structured data that duplicates contain a column with "19201935_19210346_19215508_19199482".

Answer (score 0):

```
$dupes = explode('_', $duplicate_string);
shuffle( $dupes );
$single_duplicate = $dupes[0];
```

Comment: This is happening before its passed for display. so what happens of the next row has different duplicate ids?

Comment: I was assuming it was stored in a database and you were looping through rows